# Move the constant to variable in the where clause dramatically change the execution plan?

Tags: sql-server, parameters, sql-execution-plan

I created an index for a complex view. Running the following query in Sql Server management studio takes 0 to several seconds. And the query plan shows 99% of the cost is on the Index Seek on the index I created for the main big table. (With the total subtree cost of 7.5)

```
select * from ComplexView where id = 10000 and theDate = '1/1/2018'
```

However, the following query

```
declare @id int = 10000, @theDate datetime = '1/1/2018'
select * from ComplexView where id = @id and theDate = @theDate
```

takes a long time (3 to 10 minutes), the query plan captures shows 57% of the cost is on the Table Scan on the main big table (plus 10% filter on it and 14% Hash match and 17% sort, with the total subtree cost of 260).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first query will have a query plan compiled based on the values of your literals `10000` and `'1/1/2018'` and the histogram statistics on the tables involved.

The second is essentially "optimise for unknown" as the values of the parameters are deemed to be not known at compile time. When you use local variables SQL Server is not able to use the histogram anymore. Instead it uses the information on the density vector of the statistics object.

This is known and expected behaviour (although it might be surprising if you are unaware of it).

You turned on show actual execution plan for both queries and found they had different plans.

If you happen to first run a query with 'typical' values (based on the distributions of the columns involved) you will get a cached plan that works for most values of your filters.

Assuming your statistics up to date, try this:

```
declare @id int = 10000, @theDate datetime = '1/1/2018'
select * from ComplexView 
where id = @id and theDate = @theDate
option(recompile)
```

Do you get a more reasonable plan?

Using `option(recompile)` is one of those 'it depends' answers! If the query is a reporting query (by that I mean it's relatively long running and not run frequently) then consider adding it. It tells SQL Server not to cache the plan and recompile a new plan on each execution. It has the drawback that you won't see the plan in the cache and you pay the (relatively small compared to a long running query) cost of the plan compilation on each execution.

If it's a critical reporting query then I would add `option(recompile)` to ensure you never get an inappropriate query plan.

Comment: Adding `option(recompile)` make it must faster and it uses index seek on another index. The statistics are updated. Why there is a need to recompile the query? Should I add it on the production?

Comment: Curiously, why most of the case I don't need `option (recompile)` to get the right plan, even with parameters?

Comment: If you happen to first run a query with 'typical' values (based on the distributions of the columns involved) you will get a cached plan that works for most values of your filters.

Comment: So the issue may be resolved by clear the cache and run it with the parameters to create a new cache?

Comment: it would, but clearing the cache is far more heavy than simply recompiling an individual query